# groups permissions not working

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, file-permissions

I'm confused why is this not working? Admin group is having access on the /opt directory and I'm the member of that group and still I can not make a new directory there.

```
vita@eldamar:/opt$ ll /
total 120K
drwxrwxr-x  14 root admin 4.0K Aug 26 20:32 opt/
vita@eldamar:/opt$ id
uid=1000(vita) gid=1000(vita) groups=120(admin),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),1000(vita)
vita@eldamar:/opt$ mkdir /opt/x
mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/x': Permission denied
```

Does anyone has any idea how this can happen? It is really strange :)

Comment: Is anything mounted at /opt or is it part of the root filesystem?

Comment: To answer Paul's question, type `df /opt`